# Django multi-DB multitenancy with MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, multi-tenant, database

Is there software that provides multi-DB multi-tenant support for Django and works with MongoDB?

I think I only need multi-tenancy at the database level and maybe at the schema level but not at the application level.

I have a pretty complicated user model. Some users can view certain data inputted by other users. Users usually belong to organizations. Organizations can be nested hierarchically, and there can be similarities in how the application is configured for users within the organization (e.g., all users within an organization will fill out the same form, unless that's overriden for an individual user). Sometimes certain data that users submit can be viewed by users outside of their organization and even outside of the hierarchy that their organization's within. Organizations using the app can be competitors, and the data we're dealing with is sensitive, so it needs to be very secure. It also needs to be developed very quickly.

I'm thinking of giving each user their own DB, and then either having shared DBs or one shared DB with multiple schemas in order to store configurations that are shared across users within organizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi tenancy on MongoDB is perfectly viable, we are using it in production at [onliquid.com](http://onliquid.com).

I don't know of any lib, plugin or specific software that does it for you but it is doable with not that much effort. If you want to dive into it I would advise to pay special attention to how the driver you are using behaves when selecting the database to read and write to and start working on that. Also take a look at MongoDB configuration options like `smallfiles` and `directoryperdb` which allow you to better manage the differences and avoid some problems.

I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.onliquid.com/big-data-meets-multitenancy-part-one/) some time ago about this for Ruby on Rails using Mongoid, most of the details are applicable to all web frameworks and specific to the inner workings of MongoDB.